# Looking for aws eks cluster yaml template for master node using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-eks

I am planning to create eks cluster using cloudformation ,i am looking for template from amazon,not getting the path for creating eks cluster master node yaml file.
i got from gitlab:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/d17afb59ed6d43249daa5acd7b2e673408d7094f?merge_request_iid=17036

please let me know if anywhere i can find.
i got for cluster-node/workernode group template
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml

Comment: You might have a look [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-eks-readme.html#amazon-eks-construct-library) that is powered by Cloudformation with much better high level support.

Answer (score 1):

EKS is managed Kubernetes services. AWS creates the control plane based on EKS ressource type on your CloudFormation template.

```
Resources:

  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${ClusterName}
      Version: !Sub ${KubernetesVersion}
      RoleArn: !Sub ${ClusterRole}
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
```

Next, users have to add their worker nodes (NodeGroup).